# When orientation is changed, Custom Alertview resizes to its default size

Tags: ios, uialertview

In my application i have created a custom alertview. While rotating the device , custom alertview is also rotated but the alertview's size is automatically changed. How can i fix this?

[image: First image is my alertview before rotation]

[image: Second Image is after rotation]

First image is my alertview before rotation and the Second Image is after Portait/Landscape rotation.
Can someone help me to fix this?

I used the following code to resize the frame of alertview,

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if( UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ) )
 {
 alertView.frame = CGRectMake(208.0f, 412.f, 352.f, 180.f);     
}
else
{
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(336.0f, 284.f, 352.f, 180.f);      
}
```

This issue happens, if the device is rotated when alertview is present in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are subclassing the standard uialertview, then u have to set the frame using the below

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
frame.size = CGSizeMake(352.0, 180.0);
[super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Now the frame is not resized but label and button alignments are getting auto-resized.

Comment: You can add and use your own labels instead of the ones from the original alert view. Hide the originals and use yours!

Answer (score 0):

just write following two lines

```
[YourCustomView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
YourCustomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Try this

Comment: its not working. is there any other ways to sort out this issue

Comment: @iOS Developer Where to write your code in viewController or in CustomAlert ViewController.

Comment: before this line `[self.view addSubView:YourCustomView];`

Comment: Please provide code of creating a custom alert. so i can get understood that what is going wrong....